Downloading files from Browser thorugh Drag & Drop Method to Double Commander
Operating System: Windows 11 Pro, Version 23H2
External File Explorer: Double Commander 1.0.9 Rev. 222
Web Browser: Google Chrome Version 128.0.6613.114 64 bit
I have observed that if I drag and drop GMAIL Attachment from Google Chrome to Widows File Explorer then it gets downloaded to particular directory (folder) but the same doesn't work if I drop the attachments on Double Commander. Any idea why is not working? I think for transferring the file, double commander would be using the same background process/tools which Windows File Explorer does use.

The issue is not the process it uses but what triggers the download.

@ChanganAuto Ok. How can I analyze it?

I mean, there's something in the GMail's page code that triggers the download to where you dropped it in the File Explorer. File Explorer is a standard Windows feature so it's easy to code something like that. But the same code is unaware of other software.
